# Show blocks instead of specific address on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to do a mapping app that will show the blocks instead of a specific address (even on full zoom)

For instance, if this was Zillows-like app and there were 2 houses one on 170 Main Street and another on 175 Main Street I just want to highlight the block.  Either via an info marker at 170 Main St (in the street and not on the house) that would have a 2 in it or maybe draw a polyline on 170 - 180 Main St.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This google link explains how to draw ploygones on a google map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way you suggested will work. You could draw a polyline from each address, or two different markers at each. You could also do poly shapes to draw around the block, and even add an alpha for the fill so it has a highlight effect.

How you go about this depends on how you are getting the addresses. Do you have preset latlngs? Or is the user dynamically searching for address?